# In c++ how to hide that a class uses shared_ptr to abstract class in it's private members

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

I would like to use shared ptr to store an abstract class (A) inside of an other class (B), but I don't want to reveal that it will be stored in a shared ptr in B.
Is it possible?

The reason I don't want to reveal it, because I think it is nicer if a constructor expects e.g a const reference to an object instead of a shared_ptr

An example:

```
class Renderer {
public:
   void render() = 0;
};

class GLRenderer : public Renderer {
public:
   void render() {}
};

class HeadlessRenderer : public Renderer {
public:
   void render() {}
};

class Layer {
public:
    Layer(const Renderer &renderer) {
        // here is the problem that make_shared needs a concrete class
        m_Renderer = std::make_shared<Renderer>(renderer);
    }
private:
    std::shared_ptr<Renderer> m_Renderer; 
};
```

Comment: Either store reference, or pass shared_ptr (note that storing references is a slight code smell)

Comment: storing as reference makes it impossible to copy the class

Comment: Then you have to store a pointer ¯\\_\(ツ\)\_/¯

Comment: you'd have to add a `clone` pure virtual method to `Renderer` but that'd have to return a smart pointer too. If you're transferring ownership in a constructor it's quite normal and expected to take the parameter as some form of smart pointer. By taking a reference you're indicating that you aren't going to keep hold of `renderer`, a `shared_ptr` states that you are going to keep it and a `unique_ptr` states that you're going to take it away from the caller

Comment: `std::make_shared<Renderer>(renderer)` won't work since `Renderer` is abstract. You could make the constructor be a template, though, then you would know the concrete class to copy, eg: `template<typename RendererClass> Layer(const RendererClass &renderer) { m_Renderer = std::make_shared<RendererClass>(renderer); }`

Comment: @AlanBirtles this clone method could work that it returns a raw pointer, and inside the constructor I would use m_Renderer.reset(renderer.clone()) ?

Comment: If you're going to use raw pointers then why not just have `Layer` take a raw pointer? The whole point of smart pointers is that a pointer is always owned by somebody and no matter what happens it won't be leaked (bar a few edge cases like circular `shared_ptr`s)

Comment: Because I don't want to use raw pointers as private members, I don't want to forget to delete them, so I want to use smart pointers where possible, but hide it from outside.

Comment: As an aside, as an early C++ programmer, almost always when you think you may want a shared_ptr, you don't.

Comment: @xaxxon It can be a uniq_ptr instead of a shared_ptr, but I also would not want to reveal that

Comment: raw pointers are good for "non-owning" pointers.   As others have said using references is a slight frown.. it also inhibits certain behaviors in C++ in terms of autogenerating constructors (IIRC)

Comment: I would change `Layer(const Renderer &renderer)` to `Layer(std::unique_ptr<Renderer> renderer)` which conveys to the caller that they are **passing ownership** of the `renderer`, and then use that to initialize the `std::shared_ptr<Renderer>` member variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most straightforward way to accomplish this would be if the abstract class defines a method that a subclass uses to clone itself, something like:

```
class Renderer {
public:
   void render() = 0;
   virtual Renderer *clone() const=0;
};

class GLRenderer : public Renderer {
public:
   void render() {}
   Renderer *clone() const { return new GLRenderer{*this}; }
};
```

And the constructor uses this:

```
Layer(const Renderer &renderer) : m_Renderer{renderer.clone()} {}
```

Note that every subclass now becomes responsible for overriding and implementing `clone()`.

Alternatively, `clone()` can return a `std::shared_ptr` right off the bat, with each implementation of `clone()` using `std::make_shared`.